# Regex match in a middle of a string java

Tags: java

I'm writting a program that takes two Strings as input, and search through the second if the first one is present. To return true, the first String has to be in a middle of word inside the second String. It cannot begin/end a word in the second String.

Exemple 1 (must return `true`):

```
String s1 = "gramm";
String s2 = "Java is a programming langage"
```

Exemple 2 (must return `false`):

```
String s1 = "cook";
String s2 = "Java is not a cooking langage"
```

Here is my non-working code:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String part = scanner.nextLine();
 String line = scanner.nextLine();

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+"+part+"\\w+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
 System.out.println(matcher.matches()) ;
```

Comment: ?Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: No I'm just getting the wrong answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current pattern is fine, but if you just want a true/false answer you might want to use `String#matches` here:

```
String s1 = "gramm";
String s2 = "Java is a programming langage";
if (s2.matches(".*\\w" + s1 + "\\w.*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Your answer provides the correct result, thanks. But since you said my pattern was correct, why was I getting a wrong answer ?

Comment: @momodjib From the [Javadoc for Matcher#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) you can see that `matches()` attempts to match the pattern against the _entire_ input.  You would need `.*\\w+gramm\\w+.*` in order for that to work.

Comment: Oh man, I actually knew that matches() worked like that, I just thought the issue was elsewhere ^^. Thanks @Tim, great answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the regex as below. This will work for all scenarios like if the string contains number or other special characters.

```
String part = "cook";
String line = "Java is not a cooking langage";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+" + part + ".+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
System.out.println(matcher.matches()) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

`if(str1.Contains(str2.toLowercase()))
{
}`